# Site speed when using ddos protection by cloudflare

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, security, cloudflare

I've recently noticed an increase of sites using `ddos protection by cloudflare` and wondering the effects on both user experience and SEO. I've notice these redirect messages last from anywhere from 2 seconds up to a whopping 10secs, which brings me to my questions.

- Does Googlebot ever trigger the ddos protection?
- Whats the average redirect time generally?

Comment: Could you specify what the "redirect message" is? Because 2seconds seems an aweful lot for a redirect. Not that the question needs it, just to give it a bit background, I know about DDOS protection, but this seems like a huge cost in de UX

Answer (score 2):

> Does Googlebot ever trigger the ddos protection?

No. The DDoS protection also shouldn't block search engine crawlers.

> What's the average redirect time generally?

About 5 seconds (must have JavaScript and cookies enabled to pass the check).